# Validations in knockout ? Fiddle provided

Tags: jquery, html, validation, knockout.js

I'm trying to do validations for controls with are dynamically generated . check my fiddle link below

**Point 1 :** when i am dynamically generating controls at that point i dont have ID'S . so jquery validation is out of question at this point

**Point 2 :** well i am dealing with observables . so i found some articles using `.extend` doing some basic validations . As i am dynamically generating controls in rows and now i am confised thinking How to make the validations work cool .

**Fiddle link** : http://jsfiddle.net/JL26Z/16/  //this contains my senario completly explained

Well any sort of ideas is much appreciated

Thank you

Comment: why -1 ? proper explanation is appreciated . I kept my efforts and i feel its a disgraceful thing to down vote without mentioning a reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a validation object and check that this has no errors like so:
The key sections are in `function Phone()` and the `self.save` method;

## ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kohan/JL26Z/17/))

## HTML

```
<form id="employeeForm" name="employeeForm" method="POST">
    <script id="PhoneTemplate" type="text/html">
        <div>
            <div>
                <label>Country Code:</label>
                <input type="text" id="txtCountryCode"  data-bind="value:Code" />
            </div>
            <div><br/>
                <label>Date:</label>

                <input type="text" data-bind="value: Date"  />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Phone Number:</label>
                <input type="text" class="txtPhoneNumber" data-bind="value:PhoneNumber"  />
            </div>
            <input type="button" id="btnRemove" 
              value="Remove" data-bind="click: $parent.remove" />
        </div>
    </script>
    <div>
        <h2>Employee Information</h2>
        <div data-bind="template:{name:'PhoneTemplate', foreach:PhoneList}">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" id="btnAdd" 
              value="Add Another" data-bind="click: add" />
            <input type="submit" data-bind="click: save" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

## JS

```
function Phone() {
    var self = this;
    self.Code = ko.observable("");
    self.Date = ko.observable("");
    self.PhoneNumber = ko.observable("");

    self.Validation = ko.validatedObservable([
        self.Code.extend({ required: true }),
        self.Date.extend({ required: true }),
        self.PhoneNumber.extend({ required: true })
    ]);
}

function PhoneViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.PhoneList = ko.observableArray([new Phone()]);
    self.remove = function () {
        self.PhoneList.remove(this);
    };
    self.add = function () {

        self.PhoneList.push(new Phone());
    };

    self.save = function () {
        var errors = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.PhoneList(), function (item) {
            if (item.Validation.errors().length != 0) {
                item.Validation.errors.showAllMessages();
                errors++;
            }
        });
        if(errors) {
            alert("has employee errors");
        }
        else {
            alert("all good");
        }
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new PhoneViewModel());
$(document).ready(function () {

});
```

## CSS

```
.validationMessage{
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much  mate for your time :) well that a head start for me . well to do different validations is there any proper place i can look into . cheers . God bless . awesome mate

Comment: What do you mean by different? You can find information on the knockout validation plugin here: https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation

Comment: hi , i am getting error at this point `item.Validation.errors().length != 0` validation is getting null ? any ideas

Comment: You need the validation plugin i imagine. https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation

Comment: yes added but i just know came to know its not getting refered on load . cheers ty for info

Comment: mate cant i do like displaying text under the textbox or making textbox red color like that . i cant display lengthy text side words which makes my design fall apart ?

Comment: To prevent the red messages you need to use 'ko.validation.init({insertMessages: false});'

Comment: awesome bro .! thank you so much well i am also trying to add red background color if validation fails to particulr control ? is this possible with the present code ?

Comment: You can do a binding like this: `data-bind="value:Code, css:{validationError: !Code.isValid()}"` it will apply the css class validationError when the binding is invalid. Note, it now displays the error instantly. Have fun getting the box to start black and going red when you click the button :) [Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kohan/H4TPx/] If you have any other questions please post a new question, it makes it easier for others to find the information they need.

Answer (score 1):

Where you want to do your validation you can access each control easily from your `self.PhoneList()` observable.

```
self.save = function () {
    var phonelist = self.PhoneList();
    for(var i=0;i<phonelist.length;i++){
        phonelist[i].Validate();
    }
}
```

See attached fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/JL26Z/25/

Comment: `doValidation(phonelist[i]);` is dovalidation inbuild one . can you pleas eloborate a bit mate

Comment: You have to write dovalidation yourself. I've moved it in the Phone Model as that makes more sense and renamed it to Validate. See attached fiddle with a very basic implementation.